# LINQ to SQL does not work properly with Automapper

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, automapper

I have used Automapper for a long time without any difficulty for a long time and I have been trying to integrate this wonderful tool into my LINQ to SQl framework recently. I have following code:

```
using (var ps = new Promotionalsponsorship(constr))
{
   var applicationToSave = Mapper.Map<ApplicationModel, Application>(application);    

    if (applicationToSave.ApplicationId == default(int))
    {
        ps.Application.InsertOnSubmit(applicationToSave);
    }                

    ps.Application.Context.SubmitChanges();
 }
```

What I am trying to do here is UPSERT method where I am saying that if there is anew record with id = 0 then insert OR update. Funny thing here is that insert works BUT **ps.Application.Context.SubmitChanges();** does not work when I update the context using Automapper as I did that in the code above.

Now, if I update context using simple property assignment like following:

```
applicationToSave.Name = "Beautiful";
if (applicationToSave.ApplicationId == default(int))
{
    ps.Application.InsertOnSubmit(applicationToSave);
}
ps.Application.Context.SubmitChanges();
```

This one works. I feel like Automapper does something to context object which makes it detached from the DB. I am not sure. How can I make it work with AutoMapper?

Comment: Just a guess. But if you have tracking changes enabled, then automapper's setting of the properties probably isn't going to trigger the change tracking (due to reflection). You might try manually marking the entity as modified after the mapping and see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change tracking only works for loaded entities. Automapper is creating a new object for you, which is completely unrelated to EF - it's just a normal object as far as the code cares. You'll need to do something like this:

```
using (var ps = new Promotionalsponsorship(constr))
{
    var applicationToSave = ps.Application.Find(application.ApplicationId);
    if (applicationToSave == null)
        applicationToSave = new Application();

    Mapper.Map(application, applicationToSave);  //May not be accurate, search for the  
                                          //method that writes into an existing object

    if (applicationToSave.ApplicationId == default(int))
    {
        ps.Application.InsertOnSubmit(applicationToSave);
    }                

    ps.Application.Context.SubmitChanges();
 }
```

That is, you load the existing application (or create a new one), then fill it with automapper.